# What Linux partitions must be bootable?

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, bootable-media

Specifically regarding `/` and `/boot` partitions.  What dictates a Linux partition be bootable (requiring a bootable flag)?

Answer (score 0):

Since Linux uses GRUB, it doesn't care about the partition being marked as bootable. You can even boot Linux from an extended partition.

When GRUB is loaded, it uses a data file to determine where all the bootable Operating Systems are found.

Comment: Do we mean GRUB?  Grep is command line tool in linux.

Comment: You're right. I must have been asleep when I typed that.

Comment: The Debian installer provides a checkbox allowing marking of partitions as bootable.  What purpose does this serve?

Comment: If you use GRUB and start Windows, GRUB spawns the Windows bootloader. The bootloader looks at the boot flag before it starts Windows. If you have a DOS OS (Dr DOS, FreeDOS, ...), it may also need the boot flag set. Microsoft OSes are pigs, they want to be the *only* OS on your drive.

Answer (score 0):

The bootable flag is used by the Microsoft MBR to decide which partition to boot from ("chain-load" in GRUB terminology).  When you install a Linux distribution, that Microsoft MBR gets replaced by GRUB's MBR code, which doesn't care about the partitions' bootable flags because it has its own, more sophisticated, way of deciding how to proceed.

The bootable flag really only "should" be set on partitions that are meant to be chain-loaded (i.e. the partition's boot sector has its own boot code).  That's true of Windows partitions but not Linux partitions.  But if you're using GRUB (or something else like LILO), it doesn't really make a difference which partitions have the flag.

Comment: Not just by the Microsoft MBR, but also by the syslinux MBR.